# Modifying a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Case "END-BOX"
    EndBox = ActiveCell.Row
    Selection.Offset(-1, 2).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    TotalCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Col = 4

    Cells(EndBox, Col).Select

    For i = EndBox To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, Col).Value <> "" Then
            n = n + 1
        Else
            Cells(i, Col).Value = n
            Cells(i, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            n = 0
        End If
    Next

    Range(EndBox).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, -2).Select
```

It results in green cells appearing on the end-box lines, as well as the new-box lines. I would only like the new-box lines to color. Is there any way to modify the code so that it does do this?

[Here](http://wikisend.com/download/322866/Stock%20Sheet%20Copy.xls) is my workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the line that says:

`Cells(i, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 4`

This is the line that is setting the color of the cells.

To color ONLY the rows with "new-box" in column B, change that line to:

`If Cells(i, Col).Offset(0, -2).Value = "new-box" Then Cells(i, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 4`

Note: this will not undo color formatting previously applied.

Comment: Sorry, I should of clarified. I do want the code to colour the cells, but only the rows with "New Box", it seems to colour both and I'm not sure how to begin modifying it.

Comment: see revision to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Autofilter instead of Looping. You are checking for "New Box" in Col B so use this code.

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

With Sheets("Spare")
    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("B1:B" & lRow) 'Filter, offset(to exclude headers)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="NEW-BOX"
        Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End With

    '~~> Remove any filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```